# What will be next at the bottom row and why?

Tags: sequence

[image]

There is a stack made of 6 squares. As you can see there are yellow squares between red ones. The question is what will be the next row like? And why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> **Number 2** because the boxes represent binary values of the sequence of squares.
>  Red is 0
>  Yellow is 1
>  000001 1
>  000100 4
>  001001 9
>  010000 16
>  011001 25
>  100100 36
>  and now
>  110001 49